# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel_instagram_master' (SQL: select * from `images`)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp

Estoy con php y laravel y quiero traer datos de la base y mostrarlos por pantalla y me tira `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel_instagram_master' (SQL: select * from` images`)` ..lo unico que me hace ruido es que yo tuve que cambiar el puerto 3306 al 3307 en mysql(xampp) Y ADEMAS cuando voy a localhost/phpmyadmin debo ingresar password(la pass que me pide es la que puse en workbench hace un tiempo cuando tuve que trabajar con java para la facultad), desde mi ignorancia creo que tengo un temita con la configuracion pero no encuentro como solucionarlo!

```
use App\Image;

Route::get('/', function () {
    $images = Image::all();
    foreach($images as $image){
        echo $image->image_path."<br/>";
        echo $image->description."<br/>";
        echo $image->user->name.''.$image->user->surname."<br/>";
        
        if(count($image->comments)>=1){
            echo '<h4>COMENTARIOS</h4>';
            foreach($image->comments as $comment){
                echo $comment->user->name.'  '.$comment->user->surname.':';
                echo $comment->content.'<br>';
            }
        }
        echo 'Me gusta: '.count($image->likes);
        echo "<hr/>";
    }

    return view('welcome');
});
```

y me devuelve este error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel_instagram_master' (SQL: select * from `images`)
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=laravel_instagram_master
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: el campo se llama images

Comment: logras acceder a la misma base en workbench y phpmyadmin, ya verificaste la configuración de xampp, verificaste que la db existe?

Comment: si, lo que pasa tambien es que workbench esta laburando con puerto 3306 y y en xamp mysql esta con puerto 3307